# Typeorm delete many to many relation not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a nestJS project, an analytical package entity and user entity, user can like packages , to handle this , I made an uni-directional many to many relation in analytical package entity :

```
@Field(() => [User], { nullable: true })
@ManyToMany(() => User, {
    cascade: true,
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    orphanedRowAction: 'delete',
})
@JoinTable({
    name: 'analytical_package_likes_user',
    joinColumn: {
        name: 'analytical_package',
        referencedColumnName: 'id',
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
        name: 'user',
        referencedColumnName: 'id',
    },
})
likes: User[];
```

therefore we have join table called `analytical_package_likes_user` .
but when I want to delete one row of this relation , it doesn't work and can't delete the row in `analytical_package_likes_user` and still remaining . cascade in enabled too .

```
const analyticalPackage: AnalyticalPackage =
    await this.analyticalPackageRepository.findOne({
        where: {
            id,
        },
        relations: ['likes'],
    });
analyticalPackage.likes = analyticalPackage.likes.filter((e) => {
    return e.id !== user.id;
});
const result = await this.analyticalPackageRepository.save({
    ...analyticalPackage,
    ...analyticalPackage,
});
```

how can I delete relation data in join table and delete relation ?